# Why are my Bootstrap-5 Form Switches rendering like regular Checks on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, webpack, bootstrap-5, ios15

I have some simple [Switches](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/forms/checks-radios/#switches) that work fine on my pc however, on my iPhone they are rendered just like [Checks](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/forms/checks-radios/#checks) (see images).
I'm using Bootstrap v5.1.3 compiled from source.
The snippet below contains the relevant html.

### PC (desired behavior):

[image: pc]

### iPhone (un-desired behavior):

[image: iPhone]

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="form-check form-switch">
  <input type="checkbox" role="switch" class="form-check-input" id="filter-past" autocomplete="off" data-filter="past" style="width: 3.5em;">
  <label class="form-check-label ms-2" for="filter-past">Past</label>
</div>
```

Comment: This now works as-is on my iPhone, maybe an ios update fixed it? idk